# excel formula that is unnecessarily long

Tags: excel

I received this excel spreadsheet at work.
The spreadsheet is basically an investment asset allocation worksheet. 
There are pension/Superannuation/investment account to choose from, the minimum operating cash will be different depending on the account type.

The minimum operating cash cell has the following formula.

```
 =IF(B30<Sheet1!$B$9,SUMIF(Sheet1!$B$10:$C$12,$B$31,
 Sheet1!$C$10:$C$12),IF($B$30<Sheet1!$B$14,SUMIF(Sheet1!$B$15:$C$17,$B$31,
  Sheet1!$C$15:$C$17),SUMIF(Sheet1!$B$20:$C$22,$B$31,Sheet1!$C$20:$C$22)))
```

However, the Sheet1 referred in the formula is not shown in the doument, see image 2, it has only 2 worksheets: "investment allocaiton" and "Sheet2".

Is the "Sheet1" hidden somewhere? I just couldn't see or unhide it.

I could write the formula in a much simpler way. However, here I am trying to understand what the hell the person is trying to create a formula that is unnecessarily complex.

Can anyone understand the formula and its reference in the worksheet?

[Minimum Operating Cash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpVCe.png)

[spreadsheet image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voUMU.png)

Regards,

Xin

Comment: If "Sheet1" is not in the `Unhide` list of your sheets, just type `sheets("sheet1").visible=true` in the immediate window of your VBA screen (alt+F11)

Comment: thanks O.PAL. yes, it is hidden and now is visible.